# Unable to view kylin web page

Tags: apache, hadoop

hbase dependency: /usr/local/hadoop/hbase-0.98.14/lib/hbase-common-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
KYLIN_JVM_SETTINGS is -Xms1024M -Xmx4096M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M
KYLIN_DEBUG_SETTINGS is not set, will not enable remote debuging
KYLIN_LD_LIBRARY_SETTINGS is not set, lzo compression at MR and hbase might not work
A new Kylin instance is started by sreeharsha, stop it using "kylin.sh stop"
Please visit http://:7070/kylin to play with the cubes! (Useranme: ADMIN, Password: KYLIN)
You can check the log at ./bin/../tomcat/logs/kylin.log

sreeharsha@localhost:/usr/local/hadoop/kylin-1.0$

Answer (score 0):

Got it, just changed the property export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true in hbase-env.sh and restarted all the hadoop deamons its working fine